# VBA Access 2010 combination KeyDown events

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to add combination keyboard short cuts (like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) to certain buttons in a form, but am unsure of how exactly to go about doing it. This is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

 Select Case KeyCode

    Case (KeyCode = vbKey2) And (Shift And acAltMask > 0)
        Form_sbfrmSalesOrder_LineItem.cmdNew_Click

    'Other Cases..

End sub
```

Keep in mind this is for vba Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The code for testing the keys is correct but the `Select Case` statement is not formed correctly.

You code should be:

```
   Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode   
    Case vbKey2
       If Shift And acAltMask > 0 Then
          Form_sbfrmSalesOrder_LineItem.cmdNew_Click
       End If
    'Other Cases..
    Case vbKey3
    .... 
   End sub
```